# How do I convert a string back to frozenset?

Tags: python, json

I am using dictionary d as the keys to dictionary dd. To do so, I convert the keys of dd to  frozensets. I need to store dd in a txt file, so I convert the frozenset keys to strings; with the resulting dictionary being "new". I then json encode "new".

How do I convert "new" back to a dictionary and convert the keys back to frozensets? (If there is a better way than using frozensets and json then I'd love to hear it).

```
new = {}
d = {'key1':'value1'}
dd = {frozenset(d.items()):'my_value'}
for k,v in dd.iteritems(): 
  new[str(k)] = v
new = json.dumps(new)

newest = json.loads(new)
for k,v in newest.iteritems():
  print frozenset(k)

### result ###
frozenset([' ', "'", ')', '(', ',', '1', '[', ']', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l', 'o', 'n', 's', 'r', 'u', 't', 'v', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: Do you need to save the dictionary in a specific format or a text file at all? If not you could simply use `pickle`.

Comment: Nope, I just need to store it in a text file then be able to retrieve it, make changes, then store it in the same text file. As long as I can do that then I'm happy. (I've never used pickle before)

Comment: Do you need to be able to edit the text file? If not just use pickle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pickle  

d = {'key1':'value1'}
dd = {frozenset(d.items()):'my_value'}

# Save to dumpfile
pickle.dump(dd, open('dumpfile', 'wb'))

# Load again from dumpfile
dd = pickle.load(open('dumpfile', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Afret you load data with `json.loads`

```
newest = json.loads(new)
    for k,v in newest.iteritems():
        ....
```

you still have a string value as `k`since you parse it to string in

```
new[str(k)] = v
```

So, you have to [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) it like:

```
for k,v in newest.iteritems():
    k = eval(k)
```

It will parse its original from from your string.